# Script for controlling .exe without using it's GUI? (Unknown API)

Tags: windows, scripting

I'm looking for a way to run an .exe file and control it by hooking into it's API. The program is Solibri IFC Optimizer ([link](https://www.solibri.com/solibri-ifc-optimizer)) and from what I've discovered there is no published documentation about it's API. Is it still possible to control the program without using it's GUI?

My goal is to create a script (.bat or similar) that does the following:

1. Start program (Solibri IFC Optimizer)
2. Open file (From hard-coded folder path)
3. Run process (Optimize IFC file, without zip packaging)
4. Save file (To hard-coded folder path)
5. Exit

This script is going to be scheduled and run automatically.

I've searched for similar topics here in Stack Overflow but couldn't find any relevant matches. I'm a novice at this but know some basic programming. This might be silly questions but I would really appreciate any tips and if you guys could point me in the right direction.

Comment: In the folder of the executable press "Shift + (Right Click)". From this context menu you can enter command line in this particular directory. Then enter the name of the executable and try some arguments like `--help`, `/?`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your very quick replies! I actually got my hands on some documentation about how to control and automate "Solibri IFC Optimizer" by hooking into its API. From what I know, this documentation isn't published somewhere on the internet yet so I would like to share it. This is how to control the program from the Windows command prompt or by using a .bat file:

**Solibri IFC Optimizer for Command Line Tool**

Example:

```
      c:\Program Files\Solibri\IFCOptimizer>"Solibri IFC Optimizer.exe" -in=d:\temp\model.ifc -out=d:\temp\model_optimized.ifc
```

Usage:

```
      "Solibri IFC Optimizer.exe" [-license] [-help] [ [-rounding] [-force] -in=dir|file1[;file2;file3;...] [-out=[file|dir [-ifczip|-ifc] [-suffix=_optimized] ]]]
```

Description:

```
      Solibri IFC Optimizer is used for optimizing Open Standard IFC files. 
       Optimization is lossless and compression is approximately 5-10%.
```

Parameter List:

```
       -license   : Print license on screen and ignores other options.

       -help      : Prints this help message and ignores other options.

       -rounding  : Use floating point rounding.

       -force     : Force to overwrite existing compressed file(s) 
                    * Default action is to ask for confirmation.

       -in        : Source folder (optimizes ifc files from the folder)
                    or file(s) (separated by ';').

       -out       : Destination file or folder for compressed file(s).
                    * If destination is a file then -ifczip -ifc & -suffix are ignored.

       -ifczip    : Forces output file(s) to be compressed .ifczip file(s)
       -ifc       : Forces output file(s) to be uncompressed .ifc file(s)
                    By default output file(s) will be compressed .zip file(s).
                    * Last specified option will be used.

       -suffix    : Suffix to be added to compressed file(s) 
                    * Default suffix is "_optimized".
```

Answer (score 0):

After receiving the documentation posted above, I managed to complete the script but I never posted it here. I'll post my solution for other people to find and use:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
chcp 65001

REM ----- DESCRIPTION -----
echo Optimizing IFC files located in the same directory as the script, using Solibri IFC Optimizer.

REM ----- LINE BREAK (REQUIRES TWO TRAILING BLANK LINES) -----
set br=^


REM ----- ITERATING IFC OPTIMIZATION AND FILE REPLACEMENT -----
set /a count=0
for %%f in (*.ifc) do (
    "c:\Program Files\Solibri\IFCOptimizer\Solibri IFC Optimizer.exe" -in="%cd%\%%f" -out="%cd%" -ifc -force
    set filename_ext=%%f
    set filename=!filename_ext:~0,-4!
    move "%cd%\!filename!_optimized.ifc" "%cd%\!filename!.ifc"
    set "file_list=!file_list! !filename! !br!"
    set /a count += 1
)

msg * "The following !count! IFC files were optimized: !br!!br!"^
!file_list!

exit
```